# Error using req.params in an express put route

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I would like to send two values as params using my Ajax put call. taskID is a integer and taskCompleted is a boolean. When taskID is two digits long (e.g. 12) my req.params shows:

```
{ id: 1, completed: 2false }
```

Below is the Ajax call and the put route I have. I want to understand how to send the parameters so that my taskID and taskCompleted do not separate.

```
 $.ajax({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/list/' + taskID + taskCompleted
```

```
router.put( '/:id:complete', ( req, res ) =>{
    console.log( 'in router.put:', req.params );
    let queryString;
    if ( req.params.complete == 'true' ){
        queryString = `UPDATE "tasks" SET "completed" = false WHERE "id" = $1`;
    }else {
        queryString = `UPDATE "tasks" SET "completed" = true WHERE "id" = $1`;
    }
    pool.query( queryString , [req.params.id]).then( (results) =>{
        res.sendStatus( 200 );
    }).catch( (err) =>{
        res.sendStatus( 500 );
        console.log( err );
    })
})//end router.put
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the two values with a slash in your definition for the route i.e. make it `router.put('/:id/:complete')` in order for this to work.

I would be better if you send the `completed` parameter as part of the request body, as the body serves this purpose, while the url identifies the resource you want to update.